# Directories in test directory causing an import error in unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'd like to have a test directory that contains other directories with golden data for testing, but I get the following.

Given this:

```
% ls
__init__.py   golden_repos   release_dir   test_install.py
```

I get this error because it's trying to load `golden_repos`:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./verify.py", line 12, in <module>
     tests.append(loader.discover(test_dir, pattern="test*.py",top_level_dir=os.environ['BASE_DIR']+"/tb"))
   File "/Users/raysalemi/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 338, in discover
     raise ImportError('Start directory is not importable: %r' % start_dir)
 ImportError: Start directory is not importable: '/Users/raysalemi/workspaces/scripts/tb/test_install/golden_repos'
```

How can I exclude directories from being discovered?

Answer (score 2):

Putting an `__init__.py` file in all the directories caused them to be examined and ignored.

This is not the same as excluding them, and now there are spurious `__init__.py` files around, but it did work.

Comment: Indeed empty __init__.py files is the way to get over the error.
Python does not provide a mechanism to exclude anything from import.